# Query DataFrame by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with words as indices. How can I get the rows whose index starts with a certain letter? I tried the query and loc methods but could not refer to the index of rows and further the first letter of the indices.

Comment: kindly share a sample data, explain more what the issue is, and post an expected output

Comment: use `df.loc[df.index.str.startswith('_test')]`